# In Laravel, how to combine where() and orderBy() when orderBy() is working on relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two Models, a `Track` model and an `Artist` model, where each `Track` model `belongsTo()` one `Artist` model. `Track` models have a `number` column and `Artist` models have a `name` column. I want to retrieve all `Tracks` where `number = 1` and then display those sorted by their Artist's name. So far I have only figured out how to do one or the other, but not both.

I would expect to be able to do this with something like:

```php
Track::with(['artist' => function($q) {
            $q->orderBy('name');
        }])->where('number', 1)->get();
```

This displays all tracks where `number = 1`, but the `tracks` are not sorted in any particular order. I get the same result if I remove the `with()` altogether. Conversely, if I remove the `where()` clause then I get all Tracks in the database, and they are sorted by the Artist's name. How can I combine these two functions? The results should look like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 17,
    "created_at": "2019-09-04 22:33:50",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-04 22:33:50",
    "number": 1,
    "title": "Iste omnis maxime inventore rerum nam et.",
    "artist_id": 2,
    "album_id": 4,
    "length": "06:08",
    "disc_number": 1,
    "artist": {
      "id": 2,
      "created_at": "2019-09-04 22:33:46",
      "updated_at": "2019-09-04 22:33:49",
      "name": "Ace",
      "image_id": "4"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 35,
    "created_at": "2019-09-04 22:33:54",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-04 22:33:54",
    "number": 1,
    "title": "Doloremque quidem voluptatibus doloribus et.",
    "artist_id": 4,
    "album_id": 7,
    "length": "18:13",
    "disc_number": 3,
    "artist": {
      "id": 4,
      "created_at": "2019-09-04 22:33:46",
      "updated_at": "2019-09-04 22:33:53",
      "name": "Bar",
      "image_id": "10"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 54,
    "created_at": "2019-09-04 23:00:08",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-04 23:00:08",
    "number": 1,
    "title": "Ut placeat assumenda aut.",
    "artist_id": 21,
    "album_id": 17,
    "length": "09:25",
    "disc_number": 4,
    "artist": {
      "id": 21,
      "created_at": "2019-09-04 23:00:08",
      "updated_at": "2019-09-04 23:00:08",
      "name": "Cat",
      "image_id": "22"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 71,
    "created_at": "2019-09-04 23:00:11",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-04 23:00:11",
    "number": 1,
    "title": "Omnis et dolores odio a eius.",
    "artist_id": 22,
    "album_id": 20,
    "length": "16:48",
    "disc_number": 2,
    "artist": {
      "id": 22,
      "created_at": "2019-09-04 23:00:08",
      "updated_at": "2019-09-04 23:00:10",
      "name": "Dog",
      "image_id": "25"
    }
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
Track::with('artist')->join('artist', 'artist.id', '=', 'track.artist_id')->orderBy('artist.name', 'DESC')->get()
```

I hope you getting my point

Comment: This works for me because I am building the query programmatically based on user input so tagging a sortBy() at the end after get() is not ideal. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort by artist's name with your code because laravel, to `eager load` artists with tracks, executes **two** queries, you should use a `join` to have one query but I give two other options (*I don't like joins*):

1) You can use `sortBy()` or `sortByDesc()` (if you want to sort descending) on the resulting [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby), e.g.:

```php
$tracks = Track::with('artist')->where('number', 1)->get()->sortBy('artist.name');
```

2) You can start querying from Artist, but you have to change a bit your view, e.g.:

```php
$artists = Artist::with(['tracks' => function($q) {
               $q->where('number', 1);
           }])->orderBy('name')->get();
```

3) You can use joins, see another answer please.

FYI if you want to debug a query just append `->toSql()` in place of `->get()` to get a string of your `SQL`.

Comment: This is good to know for in other situations, but in my situation I am building the query step by step based on user input so the join() works better for me. Thanks.

Comment: No probem, did I say I don't like joins? (with models) You should also consider, for the future, the second solution, if you change a bit your point of view is the same as starting with tracks.